# How to make ajax request to the firestore, receive an array and make new request for all items of the array in redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, redux-saga

I wanna make an api request to the **firestore** for receiving an array of users.
The array contains **DocumentSnapshot** for grades collection.
I need to make first request, when I receive users, then I need to make another one request for each user, because I need to collect all data and put it to the redux store.

```
function* getUsers() {
  const querySnapshot = yield firebaseDB.collection('users').where('type', '==', 'pupil').get();
  const users = yield all(querySnapshot.docs.map((userData) => {
    const user = userData.data();
    user.id = userData.id;
    //the problem on the next line
    user.grade = call(getGradeFromUser, user);
    return user;
  }));
  yield put(getAllUsersSuccess(users));
}

function* getGradeFromUser(user) {
  yield call(user.grade.get).then(grade => grade.data());
}

export default function* usersFlow() {
  yield takeEvery(UsersActionTypes.GET_ALL_USERS_REQUEST, getUsers);
}
```

I can receive an array of users, but I can't receive the grade information of **DocumentSnapshot** from each user. 
How I can get them in Parallel and after last one resolve, dispatch them to the redux store?
Maybe there is a better way to solve the problem?

The user object looks like this:

```
{
    fullName: "Alex Smith",
    type: "pupil",
    grade: DocumentSnapshot {_firestore: Firestore, _key: DocumentKey, _document: Document, _fromCache: false }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`all`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#alleffects---parallel-effects) with an array of effects. At the moment you're calling with an array of objects that contain effects (but redux-saga doesn't know that).

To fix this, make sure to build an array of effects first, then pass it to `all()`, then use the result to build your list of users:

```
function* getUsers() {
  const querySnapshot = firebaseDB.collection('users').where('type', '==', 'pupil').get(); // no need to yield this
  const effects = querySnapshot.docs.map(userData => call(getGradeFromUser, user));
  const grades = yield all(effects)
  const users = querySnapshot.docs.map((userData, index) => {
    const user = userData.data();
    user.id = userData.id;
    // We can get this user's grade from the pre-computed list of grades
    user.grade = grades[index];
    return user;
  });
  yield put(getAllUsersSuccess(users));
}
```